# Android OpenCV copy ROI to part of bigger image

Tags: opencv, android

I get a mat (320x480) from the camera of the phone. Then I need to process a part of that frame. I use ROI for that:

```
mat2 = new Mat(width, 175, CvType.CV_8SC3);
Rect roi = new Rect(75, 0, 175, 320);
mat2 = new Mat(mat1, roi);
```

Now I want to create a new mat with dimensions 320x480 with a black background. How do I do that?

Then I want to copy the processed ROI to the new mat at the same place it was on the first mat. How do I do that?

I am using OpenCV 3.4.6 and android studio.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to `submat()` an `ROI` from the original `Mat` (your camera frame), and then process the `submat` as a normal `Mat`, but be careful to do not clone the `sumbmat` if you want the original get the effect.

**Update according to the comment:**

```
Mat originalMat = someMat;
Mat blackMat = Mat.zeros(size, CvType.CV_8UC1); // it is your black mat
// create a submat from the original mat, and clone it
Mat roiMat = originalMat.submat(rect).clone();

..... // do what you want with roiMat

// now copy the result to the original mat
Mat dst = originalMat.submat(rect); // do not clone this submat
roiMat.copyTo(dst);
// done!
```

Comment: And how do I copy the submat to the new mat, and how do I create a totally black mat? Thanks for replying.